# What are naming conventions for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, naming-conventions

I need to create database for SQL Server, what kind of naming convention I should use?

1) Table names could be : customer, Customer, CUSTOMER

2) Field names could be : customer_id, CustomerId, CustomerID, CUSTOMER_ID, customerid, CUSTOMERID and so on...

Is there any official suggestion for naming conventions or what is most common way to name tables and fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of different and differing standards - pick the one that makes most sense to you and then **stick to it** - that's the most important part. Have a standard and live up to it!

Things to consider are:

- naming the tables - singular (`Customer`) vs. plural (`Customers`)
- naming the tables - with or without prefix, and if with: what prefix? (`Customer` vs. `tblCustomer` vs. `T_Customer` vs. something else entirely)
- naming of columns - any defaults? E.g. `ID` for the primary key? Or `CustomerID`?
- naming of other database objects like views (`CustomerView` vs. `vwCustomers`), stored procedures (just be sure to avoid `sp_` as your prefix! Reserved by Microsoft), user-defined functions (`GetData` vs. `fnGetData` vs. `func_GetData`)

There's no "official best practice" on this - different standards suggestions have their merits, but you're basically free in choosing what you want to use for your own company / your own doings.

Just google or bing for "sql server naming conventions" and you'll find a gazillion of different standards. Pick the one you're most comfortable with, or come up with your own.